# VSCode language extension by filename pattern

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to set up custom language highlighting in VSCode extension.
So far I was successful at making it depend on file extension.
But due to some specifics of structure I need to apply language by a string in the file path.
This is the example from VSC API docs:

```
{
  "contributes": {
    "languages": [
      {
        "id": "python",
        "extensions": [".py"],
        "aliases": ["Python", "py"],
        "filenames": [],
        "firstLine": "^#!/.*\\bpython[0-9.-]*\\b",
        "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It seems there is a `filenames` parameter. But from my testing it seems that it support only full name of the file, doesn't accept regex or file path.

Is there a way to enable language by a part of file path. For ex.:
we have a file `\someFolder\Important\file.file`, apply our custom language to all file in that have `Important` in their path.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filenamePatterns`, which allows glob matching. So, in your package.json:

```
{
  "contributes": {
    "languages": [
      {
        "id": "python",
        "aliases": ["Python", "py"],
        "filenamePatterns": [
          "*.py",
          "*Important*"
        ],
        "firstLine": "^#!/.*\\bpython[0-9.-]*\\b",
        "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note: the `filenamePatterns` feature is not documented.